# Flutter Android: Prevent screen edge highlight when using BT keyboard

Tags: android, flutter

I am developing an Android app in Flutter.

When typing from the BT keyboard on a page where no TextField is present (e.g. only Container), the edges of the display are highlighted green.

I don't want to place dummy TextField

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line in your styles.xml (android/app/src/main/res/values), inside the NormalTheme style:

```
<item name="android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled">false</item>
```